# How to reduce the memory footprint of web-services (SOAP and REST)?

Tags: web-services, rest, memory, soap

I was asked this question today and got me stumped.

My understanding is that in a typical implementation the web service run-time is not the largest part if the memory footprint and hence not sure what can be done to achieve this.

I guess this could relate to how complex the exchanged messages are and hence how much parsing is needed, agree?

Please note the question cover both SOAP and REST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the simple logic, the best bet is to decrease the number and size of exchanged messages between REST/SOAP service and their clients. Every message in SOAP or XML/JSON message for REST are mapped to some objects on arrival. And if the resulting objects are large, they will consume a lot of memory.

Secondly, the less time the request processed, the better, If the    object is processed fast, it can be disposed of, and collected by the    GC, or deallocated in C/C++, which will free the memory. From this follows your idea, that the faster it is parsed, the better. As long as it will allow to dispose of messages fast.

Also it is wise to switch off internal caching, if any. It will also allow for a reduced memory footprint. On the other hand, if a service distributes a lot of similar messages, it would be wiser to cache them beforehand, and to get them out as needed.